# Running chatbot on system

Tags: python, chatbot

```
import re
import sqlite3
from collections import Counter
from string import punctuation
from math import sqrt

# initialize the connection to the database
connection = sqlite3.connect('chatbot.sqlite')
cursor = connection.cursor()

# create the tables needed by the program
create_table_request_list = [
    'CREATE TABLE words(word TEXT UNIQUE)',
    'CREATE TABLE sentences(sentence TEXT UNIQUE, used INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)',
    'CREATE TABLE associations (word_id INT NOT NULL, sentence_id INT NOT NULL, weight REAL NOT NULL)',
]
for create_table_request in create_table_request_list:
    try:
        cursor.execute(create_table_request)
    except:
        pass

def get_id(entityName, text):
    """Retrieve an entity's unique ID from the database, given its associated text.
    If the row is not already present, it is inserted.
    The entity can either be a sentence or a word."""
    tableName = entityName + 's'
    columnName = entityName
    cursor.execute('SELECT rowid FROM ' + tableName + ' WHERE ' + columnName + ' = ?', (text,))
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    if row:
        return row[0]
    else:
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ' + tableName + ' (' + columnName + ') VALUES (?)', (text,))
        return cursor.lastrowid

def get_words(text):
    """Retrieve the words present in a given string of text.
    The return value is a list of tuples where the first member is a lowercase word,
    and the second member the number of time it is present in the text."""
    wordsRegexpString = '(?:\w+|[' + re.escape(punctuation) + ']+)'
    wordsRegexp = re.compile(wordsRegexpString)
    wordsList = wordsRegexp.findall(text.lower())
    return Counter(wordsList).items()


B = 'Hello!'
while True:
    # output bot's message
    print('B: ' + B)
    # ask for user input; if blank line, exit the loop
    H = raw_input('H: ').strip()
    if H == '':
        break
    # store the association between the bot's message words and the user's response
    words = get_words(B)
    words_length = sum([n * len(word) for word, n in words])
    sentence_id = get_id('sentence', H)
    for word, n in words:
        word_id = get_id('word', word)
        weight = sqrt(n / float(words_length))
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO associations VALUES (?, ?, ?)', (word_id, sentence_id, weight))
    connection.commit()
    # retrieve the most likely answer from the database
    cursor.execute('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE results(sentence_id INT, sentence TEXT, weight REAL)')
    words = get_words(H)
    words_length = sum([n * len(word) for word, n in words])
    for word, n in words:
        weight = sqrt(n / float(words_length))
        cursor.execute('INSERT INTO results SELECT associations.sentence_id, sentences.sentence, ?*associations.weight/(4+sentences.used) FROM words INNER JOIN associations ON associations.word_id=words.rowid INNER JOIN sentences ON sentences.rowid=associations.sentence_id WHERE words.word=?', (weight, word,))
    # if matches were found, give the best one
    cursor.execute('SELECT sentence_id, sentence, SUM(weight) AS sum_weight FROM results GROUP BY sentence_id ORDER BY sum_weight DESC LIMIT 1')
    row = cursor.fetchone()
    cursor.execute('DROP TABLE results')
    # otherwise, just randomly pick one of the least used sentences
    if row is None:
        cursor.execute('SELECT rowid, sentence FROM sentences WHERE used = (SELECT MIN(used) FROM sentences) ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1')
        row = cursor.fetchone()
    # tell the database the sentence has been used once more, and prepare the sentence
    B = row[1]
    cursor.execute('UPDATE sentences SET used=used+1 WHERE rowid=?', (row[0],))
```

This is a code written for creating a chatbot. When I try running this code on cmd. By using command python chatbot.py, it returns an error saying invalid syntax.
IS there any way i can remove this error and run this code on my system?

it gives error:                                                                                                   File "chatbot.py", line 1                                                                                   syntax: invalid syntax

Comment: post error code please. Where does it point to?

Comment: Usually such errors comes with a *line number*. Use your text editor to go to that line, and look around. And if you want our help then you need to copy the actual error (complete and in full) and edit your question to paste it (without any editing besides formatting). And while editing your question to show the error, then also mark out the line(s) where the error(s) are, with e.g. a comment.

Comment: it gives error:                                                                                                   File "chatbot.py", line 1                                                                                   syntax: invalid syntax

Comment: Error code please ...

Comment: it gives error: File "chatbot.py", line 1 syntax: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

What version of Python are you running and in what environment? I ran this code on my Python 3.70b4 under Windows and it worked fine except for line 52:
    H = raw_input('H: ').strip()
Which you have to change to:
    H = input('H: ').strip()
This is probably unrelated directly to your issue, but the code you posted did run fine for me in my environment, after I made that one change (and of course installed any libraries or modules needed).